# Best way to access ViewData value from jQuery method in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to access a public property called **UserType** from within jQuery method which is filled with the data from database call in a controller method.

The same property value needs to be set from multiple controller methods. I filled the data in ViewData and tried to access it in jquery method as mentioned below:

**TestController.cs:**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Root")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = _dbService.GetUser(_profile.UserName);
            ViewData["UserType"] = user.UserType;
         }
```

**index.aspx:**

```
<%   var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var userType = <%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["UserType"]) %>;
            alert(userType);
        });
    </script>
```

I am able to access the UserType value successfully, but I need to use the below mentioned code in all the controller action methods.

```
ViewData["UserType"] = user.UserType;
```

which is not a good design practice.

Can anyone help me know any other best alternative to manage the above mentioned change with some sample code?

Comment: I'm coming from `Razor`, this works fine `var message = "@ViewBag.Foo";`, `ASPX` must not be much different, and instead of adding the `ViewData["UserType"] = user.UserType;` in every controller Actions, you why not use `Session` as an alternative!?

Comment: Are all your controller methods making the `_dbService.GetUser(_profile.UserName)` call in order to get this `user` instance? I guess this is the case, otherwise where do you expect to get the `user.UserType` value from. If this is the case you could write a global action filter to perform this task.